# Android-eye example Couldn't load Mp3Encoder error

Tags: opencv, video, http-live-streaming

Hi i am trying to stream video to http webpage, I have tried the following applications source code [Android-eye project](https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye) and im getting the following error.

03-23 17:12:47.672: E/AndroidRuntime(27063): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mp3encoder from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/teaonly.droideye-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/teaonly.droideye-1]: findLibrary returned null

Any help would be gratefully appreciated..

If anyone can suggest a tutorial for streaming live camera android video to VLC or webpage that would be great .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by rebuild the JNI code for all those beginners like me who are not NDK friendly,

All you need to install the NDK from below URL:

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Please make sure that you have set the environment variables like

```
    NDK_HOME -- \android-ndk-r9 {directory must contain `ndk-build` file}
    Path -- %NDK_HOME%
```

open the command prompt go to the directory where JNI code exist, mine under the below path

```
    cd C:{rootpath}\android-eye-master\jni
    C:{rootpath}\android-eye-master\jni>ndk-build
```

Then refresh your android project in eclipse and run as Android Application.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem, I didn't have the NDK installed .

Comment: how u fixed that issue .. can u explain